# NullReferenceExceptions while using latest mod_mono and xsp4

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, nullreferenceexception, mod-mono

I need help figuring out what's wrong in my mono setup. I get NullReferenceExceptions when I try to run webforms and mvc3 apps on apache/mod_mono.

Here's the exceptions I get to httpd error log when trying to load pages on a browser:

Accessing a web forms page:

```
An exception has occurred while generating HttpException page:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

The actual exception which was being reported was:
System.Web.HttpException:  ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitOnce (Boolean full_init) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
An exception has occurred while generating HttpException page:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

The actual exception which was being reported was:
System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot flush a completed response
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush (Boolean final_flush) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.OutputPage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Accessing a mvc3 page:

```
An exception has occurred while generating HttpException page:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

The actual exception which was being reported was:
System.Web.HttpException:  ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Another symptom is similar exceptions when I run xsp4:

```
xsp4

Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /usr/local/src
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

Stopping the server will not cause exceptions here. I wonder if the root directory here is correct? Which configuration file is xsp trying to read?

And here's data on versions etc:

Compiled mono, mod_mono and xsp from git using prefix /usr, versions are:

mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.4.1 (master/d3e5522 Fri May  9 20:16:07 MSD 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

 mod-mono-server4 --version
mod-mono-server4.exe 3.0.0.0
(c) (c) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc.
Mod_mono backend for XSP

mod-mono-server4 file content:
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@"

 xsp4 --version
xsp4.exe 3.0.0.0
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc.
Minimalistic web server for testing System.Web

Can you guys spot anything that's wrong here? What could I do to fix this problem? I haven't found anything usable so far.

---

I did find this with same kind of exception described, but in my case xsp is not an old version. 
https://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/